# dial tcp IP:80: connect: operation timed out

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

I've been using Google Cloud Platform to deploy my Magento
application with Google Kubernetes Engine.
It used to work but now I got that error. Here's the architecture:

[image]

and this are the services:

[image]

> dial tcp IP:80: connect: operation timed out

I'm trying to expose my nginx pod using load balancer.

My nginx pod configuration file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    tier: backend

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      tier: backend

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        tier: backend

    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: dir
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dir
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
          items:
          - key: config
            path: site.conf
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dir
          mountPath: /var/www/
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

and to expose it I run this command :

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
```

Is there anyone familiar with this error ?

Comment: Details are required to help you. What have your deployed and how are they configured?

Comment: @JohnHanley I updated and if you need anything else i will post it. thank you

Comment: Can you also provide stackdriver logs related to the error?